# Is there an algorithm for determining if a set of points in 2D space forms a closed region?

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm

I have a set of points (x, y) that I would like to know if it forms a closed region (within a rectangular 2D raster). This seems like a simple problem, but after a half-hour of googling, I was unable to find an algorithm that addresses this issue. Is there a known algorithm for this problem?

A routine written in C++ or C# (or even pseudo code) would be ideal.

EDIT:
The specific problem I am dealing with here is a drawing program where the application user is supposed to be drawing a boundary around a region of interest. I want to warn the user if the boundary that they've drawn does not form a closed region.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Math.

Comment: Is your set of points in any particular order?

Comment: Do you mean convex hull algorithm? Implementation is [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain).
When you will calculate it, you will just check if each point that forms convex hull falls into your rectangle and this is quite simple...

Comment: @JimMischel: No particular order. In my case, it is a vector (linked list) of (x, y) points that form what should be the border of a closed region.

Comment: @AdUki: I don't think a convex hull algorithm is what I am looking for here. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the convex hull algorithm takes a set of points and constructs a boundary around them. In my case, I already have a boundary that needs to be checked for closed-ness. This convex hull idea may useful for solving the problem in a different way, though. Thank you.

Comment: You have a bunch of points in no particular order. I'm fairly certain that for *any* set of three or more points you can find *some* order that will produce a closed region, provided that you draw a segment from the last point to the first, or if the same point exists twice in the list, and the ordering includes that point as the first and the last positions. So without more information about the order of the points or the rules you're using to determine whether they can make a closed region, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense to me, unless your points are all at integer locations and you want to know if they form a cycle with no points left over, where two points are linked by an edge if they are adjacent in the grid (using either the 4-neighborhood or the 8-neighborhood).  Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Here's the thing. I only want to know if the point list forms a closed region - I don't want to alter the point list at all. The points are drawn on a medical image (around the liver, for argument's sake) by a physician and can be added in any order. The region is usually ellipse-like and should be closed. When the physician indicates that he/she is finished, I would like to check to make sure that what they've drawn is a closed shape. I don't want to add any points/lines to make it closed.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: yes, the points are in a raster grid of pixels, so they are discrete points. So, you are correct about them having to be adjacent (in this case, 8-neighborhood is desired). So, I'm guessing there is an algorithm that can start at any point in the list and search for neighbors - if there is a break, then that indicates that the point set doesn't represent a closed boundary.

Comment: OK, I can tell you a technically correct answer, and also why it won't work for your actual application :-/  If there is any pixel that has only 0 or 1 neighbour, then the set of points is not the boundary of a closed region.  If there is no such pixel, then the set of points certainly *contains* the boundary of a closed region, but may contain additional interior curves that can be traced in a loop (e.g. like the Greek letter theta).  Why it won't work: unless the doctor is extremely careful, s/he's likely to draw a "lassoo" shape that consists of a loop *plus an attached line segment*.

Comment: I had interpreted your question to be asking whether the set of points *is* the boundary of a closed region -- but is it preferable to know whether the set of points *contains* the boundary of a closed region?  If so, then I have a different approach that might be more useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to know whether a given set of points *contains* a closed region.  Luckily there's an easy and flexible answer for this :)

Let's say that the point set you are given is the set of black pixels that have been drawn on a white background.  **Simply perform a black flood-fill starting from a known-outside point (e.g. (0, 0)).**  Now see whether any white pixels remain in the image.  If so, then the originally drawn pixels contained at least 1 closed region.

If you've ever drawn anything with a mouse in a crude bitmap painting program, you'll know that it's easy for **small defects** to form -- e.g. if you're drawing a freeform line, turn sharply, and continue the line in a different direction, it might be that you accidentally create a tiny bubble of 1 or 2 white pixels.  Luckily this algorithm can easily take these into account: just count the number of white pixels that remain after the flood fill, and return "YES" only if this count exceeds some chosen threshold greater than 1.  (You might want to make the threshold proportional to the number of points in the set, to allow a given number of defects per pixel drawn.)  For even more control, after flood-filling, you could identify and delete all islands of white pixels below some fixed "defect threshold" size.  Detection can be done by tentatively trying a flood-fill from each pixel in the image, and stopping (and undoing) once it exceeds the threshold size.

All of these operations, including detection and removal of small defects, take only time linear in the number of pixels in the image.  Flood fill is a simple and fast algorithm, but if you wanted a bit more speed, you could flood-fill just the bounding box of the given set of pixels, expanded outwards by 1 pixel on each side.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had not thought of this very simple approach!

Comment: I implemented a 4-neighbor flood-fill algorithm and it works beautifully!

Comment: @PIntag: Always glad to hear when something actually works in practice :)